# Why is SELECT COUNT() returning an aggregated number when I'm expecting a count of each row?

Tags: mysql, join, count

So I'm struggling with this very (*very*) basic MySQL query which is supposed to retrieve `courrier` records ordered by number of joined `reaction`s.

I have this table:

```
mysql> describe courrier;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| envoi        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| intro        | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| courrier     | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| categorie_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| reponse      | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| recu         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| published    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image_id     | int(11)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| like_count   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Which has:

```
mysql> select count(id) from courrier;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|        56 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Joined with:

```
mysql> describe reaction;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| courrier_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip          | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reaction    | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Which has:

```
mysql> select count(id) from reaction;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|       236 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On: `ALTER TABLE reaction ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5DA165A18BF41DC7 FOREIGN KEY (courrier_id) REFERENCES courrier (id);`

<sup>(backticks removed for readability)</sup>

So when I run this query:

```
SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, 
       c0_.name AS name_1, 
       c0_.slug AS slug_2, 
       c0_.envoi AS envoi_3, 
       c0_.intro AS intro_4, 
       c0_.courrier AS courrier_5, 
       c0_.reponse AS reponse_6, 
       c0_.published AS published_7, 
       c0_.like_count AS like_count_8, 
       c0_.recu AS recu_9, 
       COUNT(r1_.id) AS sclr_10, 
       c0_.image_id AS image_id_11, 
       c0_.categorie_id AS categorie_id_12 
  FROM courrier c0_ 
 INNER JOIN reaction r1_ ON c0_.id = r1_.courrier_id 
 ORDER BY sclr_10 DESC LIMIT 25
```

I'm quite naturally expecting to be provided with one row per record in `courrier` along with a additional column specifying the number of joined `reaction` records.

But I'm returned: `1 row in set (0.03 sec)`. It's the first record inserted in `courrier` and the additional column is filled with the number `242`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: use group by, the column you want to count

Comment: Also note that it's very bad to have columns without any aggregate functions on them when grouping, even though MySQL allows it. It may lead to random results in many cases, though this one shouldn't have any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `group by` clause, otherwise the `count` will aggregate the whole result set:

```
 SELECT     c0_.id AS id_0 /*, ...*/,
            COUNT(r1_.id) AS sclr_10
 FROM       courrier c0_ 
 INNER JOIN reaction r1_ ON c0_.id = r1_.courrier_id 
 GROUP BY   c0_.id
 ORDER BY   sclr_10 DESC 
 LIMIT      25
```

Note: if you are also interested in *courrier* records that have no corresponding record in *reaction* (count = 0), then use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.